# Make web app from hyper-v available on client machine?

Tags: authentication, web-application, browser-compatibility, windows-server, virtual-machine

We are experiencing some issues with the Microsoft Edge browser, and I need to test some things on my local development environment. I am using Windows 10 and my SharePoint 2013 is on a Hyper-v image.

Since it is not possible to download Microsoft Edge on Windows server (my Hyper-v), I need to make the Web application from my Hyper-V dev environment available on my Windows 10 machine hosting the Hyper-v in order to be able to test things with Edge.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it depends on how you set up the environment. If the Hyper-V VM has full network access (that is, you can ping it from your client), and if you set up your Web Application to use the machine name of the VM, you can just go to http://machineName. Or, if you set up a specific hostname that is not the machine name, or a full FQDN, you can edit the hosts file on your client (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) and set the IP address of the VM with the hostname/FQDN as the target:

```
192.168.0.10 myWebApp.example.com
```

Note that for improved (but not full!) Edge compatibility, you need to deploy at least the December 2015 CU for SharePoint 2013.